# How to use / import / require PHP library that loads on php.ini?

Tags: php, dll, php-5.5

After start learning some of PHP I had a doubt that I didn't found the answer on StackOverflow nor Google until now.

**I installed a lib on my system and I make it load as an extension on the `php.ini` file, but I don't know how I can call this extension in my .php files now.** I can't show you the lib name at the moment, but I'll call it by "php5fooLib".

I have installed the "php5fooLib" library on `/usr/include/php5/ext` and have included it on my php.ini with the following line:

```
extension=php5fooLib.so
```

And when I try to create a .php file and run it on my Terminal, I got:

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(php5fooLib): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/fernando/Documents/programacao/puro-crypto/main.php on line 4
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/fernando/Documents/programacao/puro-crypto/main.php:0
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'php5fooLib' (include_path='“.:/opt/Zend/library”') in /home/fernando/Documents/programacao/puro-crypto/main.php on line 4
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/fernando/Documents/programacao/puro-crypto/main.php:0
```

**The php file I've created is the following:**

```
<?php 

require_once("php5fooLib");

class Main {

}
?>
```

#### So, given that problem, how can I import / use / require / include a PHP library that's loading on PHP.ini file?

Comment: `require_once` is not for `.so` files. Most PHP libraries are not `.so` files, you'd typically get a `.so` file from something like PECL and you'd rarely install it manually.

Comment: So, what could I do if I didn't developed the library and I need use that?

Comment: Hard to say, considering you're treating even the name of the library as a secret. Did it come with a `.so` file? `.php` files? Instructions? Why so secretive?

Answer (score 0):

You can only use require and require_once to load .php files.

If your library is already loaded, you can use the functions and classes that it provides you